# Where you are in the top 1%

Tags: idioms

> This is a skill where you are in the top 1%.
>
> This is an area in which you are in the top 1%.
>
> This is an ability or skill where you are in the top 1%.

None of them sound idiomatic, is there a better way to put it?

Comment: I'm a native (US) English speaker. They all sound fine to me.

Comment: It really depends on what you mean, and what context it is put in.

Comment: @gotube Help me understand why my answer wasn't acceptable as an answer.

Comment: @gotube Still waiting.